# Ratio of force of resistance due to liquid to that due to gravity

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, viscosity

What is ratio of force of resistance due to liquid to that due to gravity?
For any object for example a ball falling in a liquid with constant velocity, what will be the ratio?

Comment: I'm curious about how gravity is resisting (the motion) in this case. Isn't gravity always attractive?

Comment: @TheDarkSide the resitance is due to the drag force.

Comment: You might to take a look at the Galilei number, it's a non-dimensional parameter that describes the ratio between gravitational and viscous forces.

Answer (score 1):

If the velocity is constant then ratio is 1:1